# os.environ['PATH'] doesn't match echo $PATH in python environments under linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, path

I've found that if you're developing using a python environment in linux, `os.environ["PATH"]` and the terminal command `echo $PATH` output different things.

This originated because I've added a path to `.bashrc` as follows:

```
export PATH=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Enterprise_Server1210/CPLEX_Studio/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux:$PATH
```

Once rebooted, `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Enterprise_Server1210/CPLEX_Studio/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux:
/home/santi/.local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin
```

This is what's expected. Also, when I call  `python3 -c 'import os; print(os.environ[ "PATH" ])'` from the command line, I get the same result.

However, when I'm on my python environment, the content of `os.environ[ "PATH" ]` is:

```
/home/santi/Documentos/Git/GitHub/GridCal/venv/bin:
/home/santi/.local/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin
```

**How can I access the actual system `PATH` variable from a python environment?**

If it matters I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. What does the actual PATH look like directly after you've sourced the venv activation script (i.e., not from within python)?

Comment: if you export on `.bashrc` it should only be available to interactive shells. i think the right way to change this is to change `.profile` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: I've noticed this happens when I use pycharm, maybe it is all related to that